# Error handling in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

How can I check, if a value is numeric and finite? Let's say I generate random numbers with Rf_rgamma or with my own routine. Depending on the parameters, errors could be generated. How can I check that within C and break a loop and the entire function in that event?

And how can I check if a vector, let's say an arma::vec from RcppArmadillo, contains only numeric and finite values?

I know, these are general questions. However, my specific problem takes minutes to be reproduced and I haven't been able to create a minimal example. Most of the time my function works fine, just 1 in 100.000 times it causes R to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way: check each element.  A simple demo:

```
R> cppFunction('int checker(double x) { return ::R_finite(x);} ')
R> checker(2)
[1] 1
R> checker(0)
[1] 1
R> checker(NaN)
[1] 0
R> checker(Inf)
[1] 0
R>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is important stuff.

Comment: Yes, in fact Romain committed something to our SVN to provide it directly as a sugar function so it'll work on entire vectors at once.

Comment: BTW thanks for accepting the answer. You may also see fit in upvoting it -- if you think it is worthy of a vote.  I just gave your question one too as this was in fact missing from our API -- so thanks!